# Angular 1 or Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm learning angular 1, however, angular 2 is in Beta and can be released soon.

Question.

Start a website with angular 1 and then I upgrade to angular 2?or beginning make angular 2 with typescript?.

I am in doubt what to do, I do not know if I start with angular 1 or already invest in angular 2

[on his twitter angular, put a new update on angular 2](https://twitter.com/angularjs/status/719940996859961344)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions to ask or not to ask and how to ask good questions. This might contain some information https://github.com/escardin/angular2-community-faq

Comment: If it's a new project, and you are new to both Angular1 and Angular2, then go with Angular2, because sooner or later everyone will catch up with Angular2.

Comment: Random question, but go with Angular 1. Without it you will get confused directly going to A2.

Comment: @Peterson, I think the oposit. Ng1 will only make you confuse when learning Ng2. The version 2 is based on the ECMAScript 6 and uses a lot of its native features. Things that Ng1 had hardcoded now became native in ECMAScript6. Is better to learn ECMAScript 6 and TypeScript than Ng1 before use Ng2.

Comment: Might be, but then if you want to go for A2, why not React.js, while it is  more stable, more popular, and still the same features (component based), as A2.

Comment: @Peterson I did not say that Ng2 is the better tool to learn. I just said that you statement "go with Angular 1. Without it you will get confused directly going to A2" is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are completely different. So, it depends on your propose.

If your website cannot has any bugs, you probably should use ng1. 
If your site can have some bugs sometimes, you should use ng2.

Why?

Ng1 will have google support until at least 2018, so, dont be afraid that your site wont be up to date.

Ng2 is the future, using modern technologies and the new ECS features. Totaly different from ng1, so almost everything that you lear in ng1 wont be used in developing ng2 apps.

You must think about what you are looking after: knowledgement or a strong and stable tool. Ng1 is strong and stable, Ng2 is the future...